# KafkaProducer not reading messages

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a dockerized Spark app for simple streaming. The listener generates random numbers and sends them to Kafka using this code:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_brokers, api_version=(0, 10, 1))
while True:
    data = //generate a json with a single number
    producer.send(topic_name, str.encode(json.dumps(data)))
```

Then I try to read this data using the consumer as such:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic_name, bootstrap_servers=['192.168.99.100:9092'])
for message in consumer:
    record = json.loads(message.value)
    list.append(record['field'])
```

When I run the code it never gets past the 'for message in consumer' part. I checked within Kafka and the messages are all there but I cannot access them through Python.

Edit: I am using the [bitnami spark](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark) containers and [this](https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-single.yml) settings for kafka and zookeeper.

I just have two separate files, one for the producer and one for the consumer. I run the producer file which sends to Kafka then I spark-submit the consumer file which should just print a list of the numbers received. For this I simply do spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 consumer.py

Comment: Can you provide steps to recreate the issue?

Comment: @pissall I expanded the original question, hope it's clearer now

Comment: This isn't Spark code. This is just `kafka-python`. E.g. you could use `python:3.7` docker

Comment: And your consumer code literally **isn't printing** anything. So, what exactly is the problem?